# reverse -webkit-animation iteration for hiding element

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit

I have this animation which I use for a div appear on screen so it comes from the bottom and stays at its final position.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from  {  opacity: 0;  -webkit-transform: translateY(500px); }
  to    {  opacity: 1;  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);     }
}

.module {
    -webkit-animation: slide .4s 0 1 normal ease none;
}
```

I was thinking if it is possible that when I assign `class='done'` for that div it could take the same animation and play it reversely simulating the same effect hiding the div.
like:

```
.module.done {
    -webkit-animation: slide .4s 0 1 alternate ease none;
}
```

but it seems it always start from the 1 iteration in the second case I would like to reverse the animation so it could start from the original position and then slide up `500px`

Is it possible to achieve using the same animation or do I have to create a new one with inverted values?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific use case works best with CSS transitions, plus you get free Opera and FF 3.5+ support. This is the basic syntax:

```
#notice {
  -vendor-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
}

#notice.pop {
  -vendor-transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

When you add or remove .pop, the animation is automatically done for you.

Check out the working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLKzX/

Comment: thanks @Duopixel, that was a very good point which clearly solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by setting the animation-delay to an appropriate negative value (so it starts at the first reversal).